# How create notification on status bar using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, statusbar

how to create a notification in the status bar on android as shown below using phonegap?

This is the example of notification that i want. [notfication example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLi8S.png)

Comment: you mean push notification?

Comment: @trainoasis yeah, a push notification in android using phonegap. but the notification appear on the status bar. example like the link above.

Answer (score 6):

What you need its called "push notifications".
PhoneGap has some plugins for that.

- [plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/324)
- [sample app](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/tutorial-push-notifications-sample-app)
- [tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/)

This might also be helpful:

- [Android notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)
- [Cordova local notifications plugin with instructions etc](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification) -> here you can see how the plugin is installed and used

Be warned, that using proper push notifications you'll have to [register](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/registering-notification-service) your app first - if your notifications are not only local of course.

> To send push notifications, you will need to first register your app
>   with the push notification service (Apple APNs or Google GCM) that
>   corresponds to your app's platform.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but to anyone who is still looking, you're probably looking for this:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Push notifications allow your phone to receive on-demand notifications. What OP (and what I) was looking for was to actually put something in your notification drawer.